# Searching for one list within another

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a near-working script to search for a list of words in column B within a larger list in column A.

Sub QualifierArray()

```
Sub QualifierArray()
    Dim List As Worksheet
    Set List = Sheets("List")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = (List.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'removed +1
    Dim listColumn As Variant
    listColumn = List.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    Dim outputArray As Variant
    Dim intQualifier As Long
    Dim lastQualifier As Range
    ReDim outputArray(1 To lastRow)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim index As Long
    index = 1
    intQualifier = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To intQualifier
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                Set rngQualifier = Range("B" & j)
                If InStr(listColumn(i, 1), rngQualifier) > 0 Or InStr(listColumn(i, 1), "[") > 0 Then 'changed = to >
                    outputArray(index) = listColumn(i, 1)
                    index = index + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```

However, I'm getting a "subscript out of range" for the outputArray. It seems that index has increased to be more than lastRow, which is causing the error. I've tried a variety of fixes, like putting an extra clause like `is not empty` but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's causing the error? One clue is that removing the `Or InStr(listColumn(i, 1), "[") = 0` part` lets the code perfectly (without this clause, of course). Am I getting close to a solution? It feels as if it's not far from here....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
Sub QualifierArray()
    Dim List As Worksheet
    Set List = Sheets("List")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = (List.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'removed +1
    Dim listColumn As Variant
    listColumn = List.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    Dim outputArray As Variant
    Dim intQualifier As Long
    Dim lastQualifier As Range
    ReDim outputArray(1 To lastRow)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim index As Long
    index = 1
    intQualifier = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To intQualifier
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                Set rngQualifier = Range("B" & j)
                If InStr(listColumn(i, 1), rngQualifier) > 0 Or InStr(listColumn(i, 1), "[") > 0 Then 'changed = to >
                    outputArray(index) = listColumn(i, 1)
                    index = index + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```

---

**Note:** Changes made marked in comment

Comment: Thanks! Although your correction is correct (something else I over-looked!) I'm still getting the same error as described above. I'll keep bashing away myself, and let you know how it goes. Thanks!